# Error: Compile Error: Comparison arguments must be compatible types: LIST<CRG_Product_Set__c>, String at line 94 column 36

Tags: salesforce, apex

```
if(productSet!=null || productSet!='')
{
                ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.FATAL,'The selected product set is available in the system. Please close the window & click on ‘Select saved Item List’ button to select this product set.');
                ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);
                return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`productSet` will be of type `LIST<CRG_Product_Set__c>`. In the second part of the if condition you are checking that this is not equal to the empty string.

It doesn't make sense to compare a List of objects to a string.

I suspect you are trying to check if the list is empty and display an error message. Try something like:

```
if(productSet == null || productSet.size() == 0)
{
    //...
}
```

Not that I negated the comparison operations to display the message if the list is null or empty.